# 'onEnter' hook for Universal Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

With the [`React Router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), you can abort transition or redirect to the other route when a certain condition meets using the `onEnter()` hook.

Is there any equivalent feature for the [`Universal Router`](https://github.com/kriasoft/universal-router) so that I can listen for route changes and redirect users to other pages (for example, to the login page for guest users)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/) and then check for the condition in the `action` of a route, which is pretty much the equivalent of react-router's `onEnter`. Here's an example:

```js
// Indicator if user is logged in or not.
// const USER = { name: 'Eric' };
const USER = null;

// Create browser history.
const history = window.History.createBrowserHistory();

// Set up routes.
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/settings',
    action: context => {
      // If the user is signed in, show settings, otherwise redirect to login.
      if (!USER) history.push('/login');
      return <h1>Private Settings for {USER.name}</h1>;
    }
  },
  { path: '/login', action: () => <h1>Login</h1> },
  { path: '*', action: () => <h1>Not Found</h1> }
];

// Listen to route changes, re-render with Universal Router when needed.
const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
  UniversalRouter.resolve(routes, {
    path: location.pathname
  }).then(component => {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('root'));
  });
});

// Go to settings on default.
history.push('/settings');
```

On [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zuyakuz/edit?js,output).